# Why does my async function return only my default state on first load but works perfectly afterwards? [React Native]

Tags: react-native, async-await, promise, fetch

I have been trying to setup access to our companies api, however it seems to be using only the initial values of state when ever the function is first called. When logging the output at the moment after it should have been set, it will log the default value still. I'm not sure where my code is going awry, but I have tried rewriting it in multiple ways but run into the same issue. It does works after the first render is done.

I'm sure the issue is with the promise handling, but I just cant figure out where I'm going wrong.

```
export const TestContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [meta, setMeta] = useState(1);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const getData = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    getMeta().then((res) => setMeta(res));
    console.log(meta);
    let ObjectsArray = [];
    for (let x = 0; x <= meta; x++) {
      // console.log(x);
      let response = await fetch(`https://api.website.com`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'auth-Toke': 'some-token',
        },
      }).catch((error) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setError(error);
      });
      let data = await response.json();
      ObjectsArray.push(data['data']);
    }
    setData(ObjectsArray);
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  const getMeta = async () => {
    let response = await fetch(`https://api.website.com`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'auth-Toke': 'some-token',
      },
    }).catch((error) => {
      setError(error);
    });
    let metaData = await response.json();
    return metaData['meta']['pagination'].total_pages;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <TestContext.Provider value={{ data, isLoading, error }}>
      {children}
    </TestContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you forgot to add is to await before getMeta() function call due to which the code will keep running without waiting for meta value to be resolved. anyway this will still not solve the problem in your case because the value of meta being in a closure [read here](https://medium.com/edonec/useeffect-and-stale-closures-ea74df7ac452)

update code

```
export const TestContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [meta, setMeta] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  
  const getData = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true); 
    console.log(meta);
    let ObjectsArray = [];
    for (let x = 0; x <= meta; x++) {
     ....
    }
    setData(ObjectsArray);
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  const getMeta = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    ....
    const res= metaData['meta']['pagination'].total_pages;
    setMeta(res) 
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getMeta();
  }, []);

 useEffect(() => {
   if(meta)
    getData();
  }, [meta]);

  return (
     ...
  );
};
```